# Debugging emacs LaTeX config file without trial-and-error binary search

Tags: emacs

I have an *extensive* emacs configuration.  Unfortunately, auto-fill-mode is broken within LaTeX-mode for some reason.  How can I debug this without binary searching my emacs configuration for the error?

Alternatively, how can I make this function not set an undo point?  It's annoying to have to press undo once per word and space in the document.

```
(local-set-key (kbd "SPC") 
               (lambda () (interactive) (fill-paragraph) 
                                        (insert " ")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can try `M-x debug-on-entry auto-fill-mode`.

But my advice would be to use do the binary search you're trying avoid.  There is nothing faster. My init setup is probably at least as extensive as yours, and I sometimes think there is a quicker way to guess what the problem is, and time and again I've been taught the lesson that binary search is the way to go. It just seems slow and silly *at first*.

Remember the parable of the wise man who convinced a ruler to pay him with one grain rice on the first chessboard square, 2 on the second square, 4 on the third, and so on.  It really doesn't get any better than binary search when you have no idea where the problem is, and even often when you think you can guess the general location of the problem.  Just do it.

Comment: Remember you don't have to comment out half of your `.emacs`, just run `emacs -q` and then use `eval-region` to evaluate portions of your `.emacs` until you cause the error.  Doing this makes it seem much less intimidating (at least it did for me).